# Detecting if the silverlight plugin is installed but disabled

Tags: javascript, silverlight

Using [silverlight.js](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightjs) and calling `Silverlight.isInstalled(slVersionNumber)` accurately returns whether an up-to-date enough version of Silverlight is installed. However, if the Silverlight plugin has been disabled, it still returns `true`.

Is there a way to determine via JS whether the installed Silverlight plugin is enabled or disabled?

(note: testing in IE8 on Windows 7)

Comment: Is this of any use? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/piotrp/archive/2008/05/07/determining-if-silverlight-is-installed-using-javascript.aspx

Comment: That is the same method used within silverlight.js, so unfortunately no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with two steps:

1st step: Detect whether Silverlight is working, e.g. host a test plugin and let it invoke a javascript method like this

Silverlight

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("setSilverlightWorks", new bool[] { true });
```

Javascript

```
var silverlightWorks = false;
setSilverlightWorks(value) { globalSilverlightWorks = value;}
```

2nd step: If Silverlight does not work, you can do your IsInstalled-test. If it has been installed, it must be disabled.

Comment: Was hoping for a client side method, not dependent on the server, but as this is a solution (albiet not my preferred one), upvoting and marking as accepted.